# Python hangs when using serial.write() on my Raspberry 2

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, pyserial

I use pySerial for communication between RaspberryPi 2 and Arduino but after my first 100 write-calls it starts to become very slowly when writing.
My Code looks like this:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 2000000, write_timeout=0)
while True:
    byteData = getData()
    sentBytes = ser.write(byteData)
    if sentBytes == 4:
        print("All Data was sent successfully!")
```

Everything is fine for the first second but then it hangs and I only send like 4 bytes each second. I also saw this post [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=148713) but on my Raspbian machine a /dev/serial0 or /dev/ttyS0 doesn't exist. How I get this rushing like in the first second permanently?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very high baud rate, a buffer may be running full and cause the hick up after a short while.
Try a very conservative baud rate of 9600 and see if you have the same issue.

Also make sure your `getData()` actually always returns 4 bytes, otherwise your print statement might not get evaluated in every loop.

Comment: Ok now it's getting weird! After some more tests and reducing the baudrate to 115200, I also monitored my system resources (but this time on my laptop where I had the same problem as on the pi) but nothing was suspicious. Everything was fine the CPU usage was 100% but this wasn't a problem. The write command was still very slow. After a little bit more debugging I added a Serial.print("test"); on the Arduino. When I  then started my python script it was still very slow but then parallel in another Terminal I entered this command screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200 then the python script was fast again.